# Javascript objects and iterating through arrays with hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, hasownproperty

The following code takes in an element, taken from the DOM and the second variable is a predefined empty object. The LHS of the final line create an attribute within the attributes object then the RHS fetches the same attribute from the myEl and assigns it to the LHS. or should do. Expected output is new object with attribute id, for example, equals the id attribute of the element passed in.

```
function getAttributes(myEl, myObj){
    attArray = [
        "tagName",
        "id",
        "name"
    ];

    for (var att in attArray){
        if (myEl.hasOwnProperty(attArray[att])) {
                myObj.attributes = {};
                myObj.attributes.hasOwnProperty(attArray[att]) == myEl.hasOwnProperty(attArray[att]);
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: please add the content of `iterateElement`.

Comment: please add the rest of the code as well

Comment: oh no, please use not `Object` as variable name.

Comment: Yes I know that. but I'll change it in the question to stop confusion. Production object name = different

Comment: what is `myEl`, `myObj`? and what does the comparison in the last line of the if clause?

Comment: Your code doesn't `return` anything. Do you refer to that dead comparison? Please show us how you call this function, and especially what arguments you pass in, then tell us what the expected result is.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks. Edited the question. If I've explained it properly now, can people please remove the downvotes.

Comment: Uh, `==` is not an assignment and `.hasOwnProperty()` is a check, not a property creation or fetch? It sounds like you are looking for a simple `myObj.attributes[attArray[att]] = myEl[attArray[att]];` (and you should move the `myObj.attributes = {};` outside of the loop and you [should not use `for…in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572))

Comment: @Bergi, can you stick that as an answer - you fixed it for me. Thank you so much. Seems so trivial now.

Comment: Trivial enough for the question to be closed instead of answered, imo :-)

Comment: I tried to delete it but that didn't work. I don't know how you close a question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to figure out if element has an attribute from the list, you can use .hasAttribute(attributeName) like this:

iterateElement.hasAttribute(attArray[i]) // returns true or false